# Случаи указания типа данных в условии цикла

Tags: c++, циклы, область-видимости

Добрый вечер. Пришел с вопросом. Читал тут книгу, в одном фрагменте было написано,  что если я укажу тип данных у переменной в условии функции, то значение переменной будет иметь большую область видимости, чем если бы я указал переменную без типа. То есть без типа переменная будет действовать, пока активен цикл, но с типом данных она будет действовать и на еще одни скобки.

Решил проверить. Написал с int'ом-все сработало. Убрал int-и программа стала использовать значение переменной в цикле во всей программе и по какому-то принципу компилятор его даже изменил, по какому-я не понимаю.

Вопрос: Я некорректно понял инфу из учебника? Да, то как все должно быть на самом деле?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 int done=5;
 int howmany=3;

   for( done=1; done<howmany; done++)
   {
    cout<<"7"<<endl;
   }

   cout<<done;
  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

> 7
>   7
>   3

Comment: Что такое "условие функции"? Правильно ли понимаю, что вам нужно просто зачитать главу учебника про область видимости переменных?

Comment: Ну, если проинтерпретировать «укажу тип данных у переменной в условии функции» как «объявлю в scope'е локальную переменную»...

Comment: Приводите конкретную цитату из книги, ну и код текстом, а не картинкой. Хотя о сути Вашего вопроса знающий человек может легко догадаться, сформулирован он довольно ужасно.

Comment: В инструкции for можно объявить и инициализировать переменную. Это полезно, когда переменная нужна только в процессе выполнения цикла. Например, рас- смотрим следующую инструкцию:
for(int done=1; done<=howmany; done++)
Эта инструкция эквивалентна двум другим;
int done;
for(done=1; done<=howmany; done++)
Переменная, объявленная в начальном выражении инструкции for, считается объявленной до составной инструкции, определяющей цикл. Следовательно, ее область видимости простирается дальше последней инструкции цикла,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Рассмотрим следующую программу

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int done = 5;
    int howmany = 3;

    for ( done = 1; done < howmany; done++ )
    {
        std::cout << done << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << done << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее  вывод на консоль

```
1
2
3
```

В этой программе в блоке кода функции `main` объявлена переменная `done`. Сначала эта переменная инициализируется значением 5

```
int done = 5;
```

а затем в предложении `for` ей присваивается значение 1

```
for ( done = 1; done < howmany; done++ )
      ^^^^^^^^
```

После выхода из цикла эта переменная будет иметь значение 3.

Теперь рассмотрим следующую программу

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int done = 5;
    int howmany = 3;

    for ( int done = 1; done < howmany; done++ )
    {
        std::cout << done << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << done << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
1
2
5
```

В этой программе в предложении `for` объявляется переменная с именем `done`, совпадающем с именем переменной, объявленной в блоке кода `main`.

```
for ( int done = 1; done < howmany; done++ )
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Эта переменная в предложении `for` скрывает одноименную переменную с таким же именем, объявленную во внешнем блоке кода. Ее область определения - это тело цикла `for`. После выхода из цикла данная переменная прекращает свое существование.

Из стандарта C++ (6.5.3 The for statement)

> 3 If the for-init-statement is a declaration, the scope of the name(s)
>   declared extends to the end of the for statement.

Поэтому последняя строка вывода программы

```
5
```

уже выводит на консоль значение переменной `done`, которая была объявлена до цикла в блоке кода функции `main`

В общем случае имя, объявленное во внутренней области объявления скрывает такое же имя, объявленное во внешней области объявления

Из стандарта C++ (3.3.10 Name hiding)

> 1 A name can be hidden by an explicit declaration of that same name in
>   a nested declarative region or derived class (10.2).

Обратите внимание, что есть важное отличие в определении предложения `for` между C++ и C.

В C++ во второй части предложения `for`, где записывается условие, также может быть объявление.

Рассмотрите следующую демонстрационную программу

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int done = 5;
    int howmany = 3;

    for ( ; int howmany = done; done-- )
    {
        std::cout << done << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << howmany << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
5
4
3
2
1

3
```

При каждой итерации данного цикла `for`

```
for ( ; int howmany = done; done-- )
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

объявляется переменная `howmany`, которая скрывает переменную с таким же именем, объявленную в функции `main`. Значение, присвоенное этой переменной, преобразуется к булевскому типу. Если оно равно 0, то условие будет ложным и произойдет выход из цикла.

После цикла выводится уже значение переменной `howmany`, объявленной в `main`.

Ну, и напоследок пример, когда в предложении `for` сразу в двух его частях объявляются переменные, которые скрывают одноименные переменные с теми же именами, объявленные в `main`. После выхода из цикла эти переменные прекращают свое существование, и становятся видимыми переменные, объявленные в `main`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int done = 10;
    int howmany = 20;

    for ( int done = 5; int howmany = done; done-- )
    {
        std::cout << done << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << '\n' << done << std::endl;
    std::cout << howmany << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод этой программы на консоль

```
5
4
3
2
1

10
20
```

Предложение `for` в этой программе логически может быть представлено как

```
{
    int done = 5;

    Label_repeat:
    {
        int howmany = done;

        if ( howmany != 0 )
        {
            std::cout << done << std::endl;
            done--;
            goto Label_repeat;
        }
        else
        {
            goto Label_exit;
        }
    }
}
Label_exit:
//...
```

Comment: С некоторой долей уродства в С (по крайней мере в gcc) переменную в условии цикла тоже можно объявить -- `for (; ({int h = d; h;}); --d) ...` (конечно, в теле цикла `h` не видна)

Comment: @avp, а смысл тогда ее объявлять, если она не видна в теле?

Comment: @Grundy, да в общем-то никакого. С тем же успехом подобный блок *можно делать везде*, где допустимо *выражение*. Не думаю, что на практике  было бы приятно читать подобный код.

Answer (score 4):

Как я понимаю, вы просто указали в цикле `for`

```
for(int done ....
```

При этом произошло следующее: вы объявили новую переменную `done`, которая имеет областью видимости только цикл `for`, а после выхода из него это переменная `done` благополучно умирает, и имя `done` относится вновь к той переменной, которая объявлена в начале функции `main`. Поскольку в цикле вы меняли переменную, которая просто "тезка" локальной переменной `done` из функции `main`, последняя оставалась неизменной.

Но как только вы убираете слово `int` из заголовка цикла `for`, объявление исчезает, и переменная, используемая в цикле `for` - та же, что объявлена в `main`. Естественно, что при работе цикла она изменяется.

А вообще по вопросу очевидно, что вы эту тему понимаете неверно, так что почитайте повнимательнее учебник на тему областей видимости переменных.